# Yii activeRadioButton does not get activerecord's real value

Tags: yii

What might be the problem? I have a activerecord in $Row. The model has a property 'id'. Then I want to show radio buttons on interface like this:

```
echo CHtml::activeRadioButton($Row, 'id');
```

and when rendered on the browser, I can see that the radio button's value is '1'. But when I do like this:

```
echo $Row['id'];
```

that shows the correct value (128).
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `'id'` argument specifies what property the radio button will write to when the form is submitted. However, you need to also specify what the radio button's value will be when selected. Do this through the function's third parameter:

```
echo CHtml::activeRadioButton($Row, 'id', array('value' => $Row['id']));
```

Comment: does activeRadioButton first parameter accept CActiveRecord type?

Comment: As per the documentation, it accepts any `CModel`. `CActiveRecord` is a `CModel`, so yes.

Comment: jon but it failed. I have examined the documentation. I noticed that activeRadioButton requires 'attributes'. And activeRadioButton's 'attributes' is not from CModel. (here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord)

Comment: @fasisi: I don't follow. Where does it say that aRB requires "attributes"? What kind of attributes?

Comment: jon: aRB first parameter is CModel, second parameter is attribute, the third is optional HTML options. And if you follow CHtml::activeRadioButton source code, it will access CModel's 'attributes'. ActiveRecord also has 'attributes', but it is not from CModel.

Comment: jon: aRB requires 'attributes' that comes/inherited from CModel. While ActiveRecord's 'attributes' -- the documentation says -- is not from CModel.

Comment: @fasisi: So what is the problem after adding the `value` key? You should update the question with additional information.